# BQ fastest way to drop dataset

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a dataset, which consists of ~600 tables. I want to create a new dataset with no tables and same name using CLI.

At the moment I'm iterating through all of the tables and dropping them with "bq rm" 1 by one, but it takes ~20min. Maybe I can simply drop dataset without removing the tables first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-r` flag. For example:

```
bq rm -rf dataset_name
```

The `-f` flag means "force", so the command won't prompt for confirmation.

Comment: is this option still valid? I started getting error:"FATAL Flags parsing error: Unknown command line flag 'rf'"

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply use contextual menu in BigQuery UI to delete dataset
When you try and dataset has tables in it - you will see below form

[image]

Just type your dataset_name to confirm deletion - and you are done!

Comment: I edited original post now, that I want to do it using command line interface. -r option did the trick for me, though

Answer (score 0):

I found that just using the -f option was sufficient to delete a BigQuery dataset. The -r option, which I am guessing means recursive gave an error.

```
bq rm -f dataset_name
```